# How to include a PHP page more than once one with a curl

Tags: php, curl, include

If I PHP include this page more than once.

```
$json_file = @curl("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel={$stream}");
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if (strtolower($json_array[0]['name']) == strtolower("live_user_{$stream}")) {
    echo '<img src="http://www.pvpallday.com/streams/' . $stream . '_on.gif" />';
} else {
    echo 'off';
}

function curl($url, $post = null, $retries = 3) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    if (is_resource($curl) === true) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        if (isset($post) === true) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (is_array($post) === true) ? http_build_query($post, "", "&") : $post);
        }

        $result = false;

        while (($result === false) && ( --$retries > 0)) {
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I get an error about having the curl on the page more than once. is there away to make that not happen and still have multiple includes of it on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your function in [function_exists](https://www.php.net/function_exists)

```
if(!function_exists('curl')) {

     function curl($url, $post = null, $retries = 3) {
```

Note that the error you are getting is not related to [curl.](https://www.php.net/curl)
It happens as your written function `curl` is defined in first `include` and when another `include` is performed php tries to redefine that function again.